# Build query from list of table names with unknown length using SQLAlchemy and Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, union, dynamicquery

I'm dealing with timeseries data, and I'm trying to avoid having a many-to-one-relashionship on every row of a single record table where all records are mixed together (since the series all have different number of columns).

Instead I want to split the records between multiple tables to keep individual data series apart.

I have a lot of these tables:

```
# series 1 record tables:
CREATE TABLE records_1 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    level DOUBLE PRECISION
    #... more columns
);
CREATE TABLE records_2 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    level DOUBLE PRECISION
    #... more columns
);
CREATE TABLE records_34 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    level DOUBLE PRECISION
    #... more columns
);
# series 2 record tables
CREATE TABLE records_101 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    level DOUBLE PRECISION,
    height DOUBLE PRECISION
    #... more columns
);
CREATE TABLE records_102 (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    level DOUBLE PRECISION,
    height DOUBLE PRECISION
    #... more columns
);
```

And then I have a class with a string representing the table names associated with that class:

```
class Serie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    record_tables = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

Example:

```
s1 = Serie() 
s1.record_tables = 'records_1, records_2, records_34'
s2 = Serie()
s2.record_tables = 'records_101, records_102'
```

I'd like to be able to select all records associated with a given serie, based on the record_tables string. Splitting and stripping it of whitespace is easy, but how would I build the query dynamically?

Something like "for each table in record_tables_list, select all records from table and return all records from all tables in list" but in one sql query instead of appending results to a list in python (which I imagine is slower).

I guess I should use UNION, as I have recreated such a query manually in SQL. But how do do it with an unknown number of table names in Serie.record_tables?

**Update:**

Ok, so a raw query seems to work while joining the list of sanitized record_tables (it depends on user input (my own) so I have to clean it up to remove typos and such):

```
tables = ', '.join([x.strip() for x in record_tables.split(',')])
raw_query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tables
results = db.engine.execute(raw_query)
for row in raw_query:
    print row    # (1L, 123.0, 1L, 456.0)
```

Edit: no this doesn't work. hm.

Comment: Why don't you have all the data just in the one table, that is how PostgreSQL is supposed to be used. Code the serie in a VARCHAR column, with `'1'`, `'2'`, `'2a'` etc

Comment: Thanks Antti, I have considered that (but using a relationship back to the series instead of a string representation). It just seems so unnecessary to have all that "extra" data in a column instead of a separate table...?

Comment: Also, the series have different columns. Not sure how I would be able to do that in a single table without having lots of generic column names (col1_name, col1_val, col2_name, col2_val etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Serie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'serie'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    record_tables = Column(String(255))

    @property
    def get_records(self):
        sess = object_session(self)
        tables = [x.strip() for x in self.record_tables.split(',')]
        raw_query = '\nUNION ALL\n'.join(
            'SELECT * FROM ' + table for table in tables)
        results = sess.execute(raw_query).fetchall()
        return results
```

This assumes that all the *record* tables configured in the `Serie` have the same columns and columns order is the same.

Comment: OP stated that they didn't have same columns, and thus not necessarily in the same order either

Comment: This is not how I understand it: different series have different columns, but one series has data stored in multiple `records_xx` tables with the *same* structure.

Comment: @van you are correct, on both the table formats and the solution. Thank you very much, I had no idea it was so easy to union multiple queries.